# Spray application slf4j logging to console, not to file

Tags: logging, akka, slf4j, logback, spray

I have an application with configured logging as metioned in the akka documentaion

```
akka {
  version="2.3.0"
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
  event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
}
```

and logback.xml in resources dir:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration scan="false" debug="false">
    <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{ISO8601} %-5level [%logger{36}] [%X{akkaSource}] [%X{sourceThread}] [%X{traceId}] : %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="R" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>log/info.log</File>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{ISO8601} %-5level [%logger{36}] [%X{akkaSource}] [%X{sourceThread}] : %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${atmos.dir}/atmos.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
    <logger name="org.eclipse.jetty.util.log" level="INFO"/>
    <!-- Play2: Off these ones as they are annoying, and anyway we manage configuration ourself -->
    <logger name="com.avaje.ebean.config.PropertyMapLoader" level="OFF" />
    <logger name="com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.XmlConfigLoader" level="OFF" />
    <logger name="com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.BackgroundThread" level="OFF" />

    <root level="INFO">
        <!--<appender-ref ref="stdout"/>-->
        <appender-ref ref="R"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

and for some reason I've got only logs from external dependencies going to the info.log file, and all loging made with `ActorLoggin` trait is printed out to the console.

This is driving me madness, and actually don't have a clue what I'm doing wrong with this...

Any suggestion will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

To enable logging of Spray REST requests-responses in a separate file I use the following settings:

1) In Akka configuration: `"spray.util.log-actor-paths-with-dots":"on"`

2) In Logback configuration:

```
<logger name="akka.actor.path.separated.by.Dots" level="INFO">
  <appender-ref ref="REST-FILE"/>
</logger>
```

3) `logRequestResponse` directive in the code

Comment: Are you sure that you've correctly specified the full Actor path (separated by dots) in the logback config? You can look up the correct  Actor path in your successful Spray's log entries (in the log file or console).

Comment: I've tried with the package prefix and with specific Actor full path. This is odd. It seems like problem is lying elsewhere because I've noticed some logs from the slick library in my log file when I've create a logger with package-prefix. So this has to do something with the akka event handler for slf4j but still I have no clue what it is.